# How to read XFA form field and data in Java and how to convert XFA form PDF to normal PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext, xfa

I need to read XFA PDF form filled data in Java. And also we need to convert the XFA form PDF to normal PDF.

Comment: What have you tried? What blocks you? What kind of XFA form are you talking about? Full XFA or XFA Foreground? Static or dynamic? Can you share representative example files?

Comment: Please take the [tour] if you haven't already to get a feel for how SE sites work. You should at the very least tell us what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what results you got.